# MySQL InnoDB One Time Compression of Entire Database

Tags: mysql, innodb

It looks like MySQL has a way for table compression to be enabled, for InnoDB. However I don't care to modify the long term schema. I just need a one time compress of all tables in the db.

Is there a way to do this via query, otherwise a command line solution would be the next best thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is confusion about the term "compress".

InnoDB has `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`, which permanently writes the table in a different format.  This makes the table about half the physical size.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` rebuilds the table, possibly 'defragmenting' and squeezing out some of the wasted space.  This is rarely useful because the table will promptly grow again as you `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.

Each of those acts on a single table at a time.

What is your 'real' objective?

Comment: Your `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is what I was looking for. Thanks!